# javascript to ajax to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables

Need help. I have a page called edit.php. I am trying to send a javascript variable to a modal window that contains php, so that I can run a query to pull data.  I don't have much experience with ajax, and I couldn't find a good tutorial for this.

Here is my javascript code with an attempted ajax call:

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).on("click", ".open-EditRow", function () {
   var myGroupId = $(this).data('id');
   $(".modal-body #groupId").val( myGroupId );

   // ajax call
   var url = "" + myGroupId;
   $.get(url, function(data){
   // do something here
   });
 });
 </script>
```

I know I need to create a separate folder with a file that will convert myGroupId into a PHP variable.

Here is the modal that the myGroupId should be returned to:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelleby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form class="well-small" action="" method="POST" id="modalForm" name="modalForm">
 <?php 
   // here is where I need myGroupId returned to
 ?>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone give me an example of how that separate file should look and how to send it back to the modal on my edit.php file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a key to your URL. This should work:

```
var url = "?groupid=" + encodeURIComponent(myGroupId);
$.get(url, function(data){ // etc.
```

But jQuery can take care of encoding for you if you do it like this:

```
$.get(url, {groupid: myGroupId}, function(data){ // etc.
```

You'll then be able to read it in PHP with `$_GET['groupid']`.

Reference: [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: You forgot `,` after `myGroupId}`

Comment: So are you saying I don't need to call ajax to make this happen?  I can just use jQuery?  Please forgive my ignorance regarding ajax and jQuery.

Comment: `$.get` is one of the ways to make an ajax request with jQuery. I was talking about the need to manually create a key and escape the values, jQuery can take care of that for you if you use the syntax in my second example. @JohnBeasley